# Fullcalendar eventMouseover day in month view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar component with events that span multiple days in a month view (i.e continuous event not split into separate days on the view). I'm trying to create hover functionality such that an action will be fired that depends on both the event ID and the day the mouseover happens on. It seems that with the eventMouseover I can only retrieve the details of the event but not the day that the hover event is being fired on. Are there any solutions to this without breaking the event into multiple days?

```
//pseudo add some events that span multiple days
def calendarEvents(events)
    calendarEvents = []
    for(event:events)
        cEvent = {}
        cEvent.startDate = event['start']
        cEvent.Id = event['name']
        cEvent.endDate = event['end']
     calendarEvents += cevent

 return calendarEvents.json()


 //pseudo JS:
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    <<settings>>
    events: calendarEvents(<<events structure>>)
    eventMouseover: function(event,jsEvent,opt){
        loadPage(...+'?id='+event.Id+'&day='+<<need event day here>>)
    })

So the loadPage required the event name and the day that the mouseover occurred on.
```

Comment: Can you show us some code so we can look into the problem?

Comment: I haven't implemented it yet, but have added some pseudo code